# Android json checking for username availability

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

In my android application , I need to check the availability of username when user entering the username. I know how to do it after entering username and password by clicking a button... but I want to display it in a textview. Like if user is entering 'george' then if george is already registered that geroge need to display in red color in textview else if available in green color.
Iam giving my code I used for checking the username on buttonclick

```
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

  private static String url_create_data = "http://example.com/app/create_data1.php";


// JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_xm); 


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (isNetworkAvailable(getBaseContext()))
                        {

                        String name=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                        String phoneNo = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
                        //String sms = Integer.toString(number);


                        //Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                        //intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                        //startActivity(intent);            

                        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();                         

                        // check if any of the fields are vacant
                        if(name.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("") || phoneNo.equals(""))
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                        }
                        // check if both password matches
                        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            new CreateNewProduct().execute();


                         }


class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating a new account..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String name = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String mobile = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();      

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_data,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);             
                    i.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                    startActivity(i);                   
                    //closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    return "false";
                }       

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)

        {           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        if (result == "false"){

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    context);

                                // set title
                                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Username already Exists...!");

                                // set dialog message
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage("Select another Username. Click 'Ok' to continue.")
                                    .setCancelable(false)

                                    .setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    // create alert dialog
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                                    // show it
                                    alertDialog.show(); } 



           // Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Name already exists. Please choose another user name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this programme the username is checked whether existing or not .. when user enter an username to the edittext. and when he press the button.. But instead of that i need to check whether username is there when user enter the text in edittext .. i think that is on edittext change listner or something like that. and the result need to be displayed in a textview in the same page when user entering the details. so if user is entering 'george', first he will type g so that textview will display g but if g username is available then it will be in green otherwise in red. so he can know which

Comment: username is available at the time of entering the name itself

Comment: have a look at `http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/using-textwatcher-in-android.html`

Answer (score 2):

This is uncommon for mobile devices. Still if you want to do this then you will have to call your api every time user types or removes any character. You can do this using TextWatcher. Follow this [link](http://www.eridem.net/android-tip-006-on-text-change-in-edittext-view).

**Note :**  You should not do this as it will call api every time user changes anything. So that will result in more usage of device's battery as well as more load your server.

If username is not available then you can display in red color using **setTextColor**  property for **EditText**.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the textview's color programatically

Use text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0)); you can set rgb text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); for parsing the color from a hex value